# Ionic: How to not stack multiple toast notifications?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework

I got the following Ionic code fragment for displaying alarms / errors in an industrial App:

```
showError(message: string) {
  let toast = this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      position: 'top',
      duration: 5000,
      cssClass: 'danger',
      showCloseButton: true
  });
  toast.present();
}
```

The App triggers the error message every time it detects a connection issues, which will be also roughly on a 5 second timer.

Multiple calls to this method will lead to 2 or more error messages shown on top of each other if the timing of this code is changed. Can I somehow detect that a toast is already being displayed? Also then, the 5000 msec timer would not be necessary and I can just remove the error message again when the connection is re-established.

Thanks and BR Florian

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could store your Toast object in a variable outside your function, and call the dismiss() method before showing the next toast :

#### Ionic 4

```js
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';


toast: HTMLIonToastElement;    

showError(message: string) {
    try {
        this.toast.dismiss();
    } catch(e) {}

    this.toast = this.toastController.create({
        message: message,
        position: 'top',
        duration: 5000,
        color: 'danger',
        showCloseButton: true
    });
    toast.present();
}
```

#### Ionic 3

```js
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';


toast: Toast;    

showError(message: string) {
    try {
        this.toast.dismiss();
    } catch(e) {}

    this.toast = this.toastController.create({
        message: message,
        position: 'top',
        duration: 5000,
        cssClass: 'danger',
        showCloseButton: true
    });
    toast.present();
}
```

Comment: Hi , need one clarification . the above code is not prevent the duplicate toast, right ? It dismiss the toast and again create a new one . Am i right ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that but I think that when you call `dismiss()` the toast is also removed from the DOM

Comment: If the Toast is self-dismissed, then calling `dismiss()` will cause an error.

Comment: That's why you can wrap it in a `try / catch` to catch the error when calling `dismiss()`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45074161/prevent-duplicate-toast-messages-in-ionic2

Answer (score 4):

Here my solution :-)

```
// ToastService.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class ToastService {

  private toasts: Toast[] = [];

  constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController) {}

  push(msg) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: 1500,
      position: 'bottom'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.toasts.shift()
      if (this.toasts.length > 0) {
        this.show()
      }
    })

    this.toasts.push(toast)

    if (this.toasts.length === 1) {
      this.show()
    }
  }

  show() {
    this.toasts[0].present();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is already a toast present or not and create new only if no toast present.

```
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';


toast: Toast;    
isToastPresent:boolean=false;

show(){

this.isToastPresent?'':this.showError('No network');

}

showError(message: string) {

    this.toast = this.toastController.create({
        message: message,
        duration: 3000,
        cssClass: 'danger',
        showCloseButton: true
    });
    toast.present();
     this.isToastPresent=true;

    this.toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      this.isToastPresent=false;
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had troubles using all of the answer pre-aug 20. The toast would still present multiple times. Fixed it as simple as checking and setting a boolean value to proceed or to not proceed. By setting it directly to true, it won't run multiple times.

```js
isToastPresent = false;

async presentToast(message: string, color?: Colors, header?: string): Promise<void> {
  if (!this.isToastPresent) {
    this.isToastPresent = true;

    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      header: header || undefined,
      duration: 3500,
      position: 'top',
      color: color || Colors.dark,
    });

    toast.present();

    toast.onDidDismiss().then(() => (this.isToastPresent = false));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Ionic 4 Toast UI Component**

Show **Ionic 4 Toast** only once using below code

```
// Call this method  
showOnceToast(){
  this.toastController.dismiss().then((obj)=>{
  }).catch(()=>{
  }).finally(()=>{
    this.manageToast();
  });
}

manageToast() {
  this.toastInstance = this.toastController.create({
    message: 'Your settings have been saved.',
    duration: 2000,
    animated: true,
    showCloseButton: true,
    closeButtonText: "OK",
    cssClass: "my-custom-class",
    position: "middle"
  }).then((obj) => {
    obj.present();
  });
}
```

[image]

**Source Link : http://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-toasts-in-ionic-4-application-using-ui-components-with-plugins/**

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this way

```
private mensajeErrorEnvioTramiteActivo = false;
  mensajeErrorEnvioTramite() {
    if (!this.mensajeErrorEnvioTramiteActivo) {
      this.mensajeErrorEnvioTramiteActivo = true;
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "No se pudo enviar los tramites formalizados, por favor reenvielos",
        position: 'top',
        showCloseButton: true,
        closeButtonText: 'REENVIAR',
      });

      toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
        this.reenvioKits.reenviarTramites();
        this.mensajeErrorEnvioTramiteActivo = false;
      });
      toast.present();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';

.........

private toast: Toast;

.........

    export Class ToastService{

.........

         showToastMessage(messageData) {

            if (this.toast) this.toast.dismiss();

            this.toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: messageData,
              cssClass: "error-toast-cls",
              dismissOnPageChange: true,
              showCloseButton: true,
              closeButtonText: "Enable"
            });
            this.toast.onDidDismiss((data, role) => {
              if (role == 'close') {
                this.diagnostic.switchToWirelessSettings()
              }
            })
            await this.toast.present()  
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shows a queue of toasts one after the other with duration.

**Ionic 6**

```
  toastCtrl(color,msg,duration?) {
    const toast = {
      message: msg,
      color: color,
      duration: duration || 3000
    };
    this.toasts.push(toast)
    const timeout = (this.toasts.length - 1) * toast.duration
    this.show(timeout);
  }
  show(timeout) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      const toast = await this.toastController.create(this.toasts[0]);
      await toast.present();
      this.toasts.splice(0, 1);
    }, timeout > 0 ? timeout + 800 : 0);

  }
```