# Prevent duplicate Toast messages in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic5

I have implemented `toast` using `ToastController` in my `ionic2` project . Currently i am facing an issue with the duplicate `toast` messages . Is there any way to prevent the duplication / overlapping of toast message in ionic2 / angular2

(NB : Duplication means when I click on a button I am displaying a toast  , if I click on the same button multiple times the toast messages overlaps ) ?

### code

```
export class <className>{
   constructor(private toast:ToastController){
   }
    showToast(message) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: message,
        duration: 2000,
        position: 'bottom'
    })
    toast.present();
   }
}
```

I am calling this method on an button click .

### Edited

1. with duplicates toast (taken example using toastr , same sitaution is for me)
   [image]
2. when i enable "prevent notification" , the duplicate toast are not there within the timeout duration .
   [image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133217/ionic-how-to-not-stack-multiple-toast-notifications

Comment: may be , but my question is different . I want to prevent the duplicate .

Comment: @AnandRaj . Can you share the code that How to set dynamic message to the toast from the text box?

Comment: @Raghav Please add a question on that and share the Url

Comment: @AnandRaj . Can you share your code so that I can get help?

Comment: Please add a new question. This is question is different and already answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a property on that page to know if a toast is being shown or not before showing a new one.

### **Ionic 2/3**

```
import { ToastController, Toast } from 'ionic-angular';

// ...

private isToastVisible: boolean;

constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController) { }

presentToast() {
  if(this.isToastVisible) {
    return;
  }

  this.isToastVisible = true;

  const toast: Toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'User was added successfully',
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });

  toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
    this.isToastVisible = false;
  });

  toast.present();
}
```

### **Ionic 4/5**

```
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

// ...

private isToastVisible: boolean;

constructor(private toastCtrl: ToastController) { }

presentToast() {
  if(this.isToastVisible) {
    return;
  }

  this.isToastVisible = true;

  this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'User was added successfully',
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  }).then((toast: HTMLIonToastElement) => {

    toast.onDidDismiss().then(() => {
      this.isToastVisible = false;
    });

    toast.present();
  })      
}
```

Comment: Hi ,

This will not prevent duplicate right ? It check for the toastInstance , if there  it dismiss the current one and again create it  . 

My goal is "show toast exactly once even though multiple click  for the same button is there  ,   "

Comment: Oh, that's right. I've edited the answer, and this time if the toast is being shown, it won't be hidden and the new toast won't be created.

Comment: frm wherer "toast" comes from ? toast should be  toastInstance  . Am i right ?

Comment: Sorry Bro , Its not working .
It shows toast only once , even after the timout it is not showing toast . 
I have edited my question with images

Comment: could you please help me with this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a copy/paste issue in the answer. Could you please try again with the updated answer? Apologies for the error.

Comment: i have tried your answer . Toast will appear only once . But when i click on the button again after the toast time out , it is not showing the toast

Comment: Can you place a debugger inside of `this.toastInstance.onDidDismiss(() => {
debugger;    
this.toastInstance = null;
  });` to see if it's being executed?

Comment: Thank you very much . I got it .

Comment: could you please help me to solve this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049243/issue-with-pushing-a-new-page-from-ion-tabs-in-ionic2

Answer (score 0):

I set `preventDuplicates` to 1 in my toastr.js file, please see below;

```
function p() {
    return {
        tapToDismiss: !0,
        toastClass: "toast",
        containerId: "toast-container",
        debug: !1,
        showMethod: "fadeIn",
        showDuration: 300,
        showEasing: "swing",
        onShown: void 0,
        hideMethod: "fadeOut",
        hideDuration: 1e3,
        hideEasing: "swing",
        onHidden: void 0,
        closeMethod: !1,
        closeDuration: !1,
        closeEasing: !1,
        closeOnHover: !0,
        extendedTimeOut: 1e3,
        iconClasses: {
            error: "toast-error",
            info: "toast-info",
            success: "toast-success",
            warning: "toast-warning"
        },
        iconClass: "toast-info",
        positionClass: "toast-top-right",
        timeOut: 2e3,
        titleClass: "toast-title",
        messageClass: "toast-message",
        escapeHtml: !1,
        target: "body",
        // closeButton: true,
        closeHtml: '<button type="button">&times;</button>',
        closeClass: "toast-close-button",
        newestOnTop: !0,
        preventDuplicates: 1,
        progressBar: 1,
        progressClass: "toast-progress",
        rtl: !1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("ion-toast");
if (elems.length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
        elems[j].style.transform = "translateY(" + j * 65 + "px)";
    }
}
```