# Issue with pushing a new page from ion-tabs in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have created a sample chat application in which when a user login the application will navigate to a tabs page

```
 <ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" color="header" tabsHighlight=true>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1" tabTitle="Chats" tabIcon="chatbubbles"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2" tabTitle="Groups" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="contact"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

[image]

1. when I check the current active page from the tabs by `console.log(this.navCtrl.getActive().name);` I am getting `undefined`. Could you please tell me why?
2. When I navigate to a new page by clicking the app icon from the header`this.navCtrl.push('FriendsPage');`. In the new page when I print the current active page name it shows the previous page name "`ChatPage`" instead of "`FriendsPage`"
   [image]

### Edit: Added backbutton action

```
      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
      this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
      this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
      this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();
    if (activePortal) {
      activePortal.dismiss();
    } else {
      if (this.nav.canGoBack()) {
        this.nav.pop();
      } else {
        if (this.nav.getActive().name === "LoginPage"||this.nav.getActive().name === "SignupPage") {
          this.platform.exitApp();
        }else {
          this.generic.showAlertConfirm("Exit", "Do you want to exit the app?", this.onYesHandler, this.onNoHandler, "backPress");
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

In my case when the user navigate to FriendsPage from tabs and hardware backbutton is pressed. In normal case the view should pop. But I am getting alert message.

```
this.generic.showAlertConfirm("Exit", "Do you want to exit the app?", this.onYesHandler, this.onNoHandler, "backPress");
```

Please help me with solving this issue.

Thanks and Regards

Anand Raj

Comment: Please help me to solve this

Comment: Where do you use that `console.log(...)`?

Comment: in the constructor of both pages

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem like you and i still do not find out the answer of why it happen. But i found a way to get the correct page name.

In `app.component.ts` add following code:

```
import {  App } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(private app: App){
}
ngAfterViewInit() { 
    this.app.getActiveNav().viewWillEnter.subscribe(event => {
      console.log("current page", event.id);  <== Here is what you need
    })
}
```

Now you can get page name in **every** `viewWillEnter` event. No need to add code in each page.

Comment: let me check and will update you. The problem will comes when we click the back button

Comment: @AnandRaj: Please do not ask two unrelate questions in one post!

Comment: don't feel bad, If i follow the above method the back button functionality will break. That's y. I implemented it using the method nav.getActive().name